# Get a structure of HTML code

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup4 and I'm curious whether is there a function which returns a structure (ordered tags) of the HTML code.

Here is an example:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Simple example</h1>
<p>This is a simple example of html page</p>
</body>
</html>
```

print *page.structure()*:

```
>>
<html>
<body>
<h1></h1>
<p></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to find a solution but no success.

Thanks

Comment: When you say *structure*, what do you mean?

Comment: I mean tags in order they are in the code. Thanks for response, I've edited the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is not, to my knowledge, but a little recursion should work:

```
def taggify(soup):
     for tag in soup:
         if isinstance(tag, bs4.Tag):
             yield '<{}>{}</{}>'.format(tag.name,''.join(taggify(tag)),tag.name)
```

demo:

```
html = '''<html>
 <body>
 <h1>Simple example</h1>
 <p>This is a simple example of html page</p>
 </body>
 </html>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

''.join(taggify(soup))
Out[34]: '<html><body><h1></h1><p></p></body></html>'
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I was searching for.

Answer (score 2):

Simple python regular expressions can do what you want:

```
import re

html = '''<html>
<body>
<h1>Simple example</h1>
<p>This is a simple example of html page</p>
</body>
</html>'''

structure = ''.join(re.findall(r'(</?.+?>|/n+?)', html))
```

This methods preserves newline characters.