# beautiful soup extract tags delete text

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use Beautifuloup to extract html tags and delete the text. For example take this html:

```
html_page = """
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tr class=tb1><td>Lorem Ipsum dolor Sit amet</td></tr>
<tr class=tb1><td>Consectetuer adipiscing elit</td></tr>
<tr><td>Aliquam Tincidunt mauris eu Risus</td></tr>
<tr><td>Vestibulum Auctor Dapibus neque</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
"""
```

The desired result is:

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tr><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's what I've got so far:

```
def get_tags(soup):
    copy_soup = soup
    for tag in copy_soup.findAll(True):
        tag.attrs = {} # removes attributes of a tag
        tag.string = ''

    return copy_soup

print get_tags(soup)
```

Using tag.attrs = {} works for removing all tag attributes. But when I try using tag.string or tag.clear() I'm just left with `<html></html>`. I understand that what is probably happening is on the first iteration using `tag.string` or `tag.clear()` is removing all contents within the html tags.

I'm unsure how to remedy this. Perhaps recursively delete text from children first? Or is there a simpler approach I'm missing?

Answer (score 4):

Actually, I was able to delete the text by recursively updating the tag children's. You can also update their attributes in the recursion.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import NavigableString

def delete_displayed_text(element):
    """
    delete displayed text from beautiful soup tag element object recursively
    :param element: beautiful soup tag element object
    :return: beautiful soup tag element object
    """
    new_children = []
    for child in element.contents:
        if not isinstance(child, NavigableString):
            new_children.append(delete_displayed_text(child))
    element.contents = new_children
    return element

if __name__ =='__main__':
    html_code_sample = '<div class="hello">I am not supposed to be displayed<a>me neither</a></div>'
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_code_sample, 'html.parser')
    soup = delete_displayed_text(soup)
    cleaned_soup = BeautifulSoup(str(soup), 'html.parser')
    print(cleaned_soup.getText())
```

Comment: Genius, award-winning answer, sir!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot simply reset `.string` to an empty string since, if an element has a single child with text, like `tr` elements in your example, you would unintentionally remove the `td` elements from the tree.

You cannot use `.clear()` since it recursively removes all the child nodes as well.

I don't recall a built-in way to get the HTML tree structure without the data in `BeautifulSoup` - I'd use the following approach:

```
for elm in soup.find_all():
    if not elm.find(recursive=False):  # if not children
        elm.string = ''
    elm.attrs = {}
```

Here we are resetting the `.string` only if there are no children.

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> 
>>> html_page = """
... <html>
... <body>
... <table>
... <tr class=tb1><td>Lorem Ipsum dolor Sit amet</td></tr>
... <tr class=tb1><td>Consectetuer adipiscing elit</td></tr>
... <tr><td>Aliquam Tincidunt mauris eu Risus</td></tr>
... <tr><td>Vestibulum Auctor Dapibus neque</td></tr>
... </table>
... </body>
... </html>
... """
>>> 
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "html.parser")
>>> for elm in soup.find_all():
...     if not elm.find(recursive=False):
...         elm.string = ''
...     elm.attrs = {}
... 
>>> print(soup.prettify())
<html>
 <body>
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ah thank you for the explanation, especially for describing exactly why my original approach was flawed.

Comment: @hannahbanana2.0 glad to help, I'm trying to see if there is a more beautiful way to solve your problem..looking into `lxml` and `lxml.objectify`..

Comment: @hannahbanana2.0 btw, here is a [quite related topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24640959/get-a-structure-of-html-code) with an alternative approach - may be simpler than what we are doing here.

Comment: Oh shoot. I didn't see that post when I was searching for similar questions here prior to creating my own. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @hannahbanana2.0 okay, I don't think `lxml.objectify` would help here. At least it does not look simpler than with BeautifulSoup at all. May be I'm missing something simple.

Comment: This code works great for straightforward html elements. But in creating more complex test cases, it doesn't handle void tags well. For example `<meta>` and `<meta/>` both get converted to `<meta></meta>`  I tried using html5lib and lxml as parsers thinking that might be the issue. but neither does the trick. Any suggestion on where the issue might lie, @alecxe?