# Remove all text from a html node using regex

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Is it possible to remove all text from HTML nodes with a regex? This very simple case seems to work just fine:

```py
import htmlmin

html = """
<li class="menu-item">
  <p class="menu-item__heading">Totopos</p>
  <p>Chips and molcajete salsa</p>
  <p class="menu-item__details menu-item__details--price">
    <strong>
      <span class="menu-item__currency"> $ </span>
      4
    </strong>
  </p>
</li>
"""

print(re.sub(">(.*?)<", ">\1<", htmlmin.minify(html)))
```

I tried to use BeautifulSoup but I cannot figure out how to make it work. Using the following code example is not quite correct since it is leaving "4" in as text.

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
for n in soup.find_all(recursive=True):
    print(n.name, n.string)
    if n.string:
        n.string = ""
print(minify(str(soup)))
```

Comment: `"\1"` != `r"\1"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [beautiful soup extract tags delete text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41641040/beautiful-soup-extract-tags-delete-text)

Comment: The answer is close but it doesn't work in this case since `4` will not be removed when doing `n.string=""`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to use `text=True` when you call `find_all` and call `extract()` on element to remove it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<li class="menu-item">
  <p class="menu-item__heading">Totopos</p>
  <p>Chips and molcajete salsa</p>
  <p class="menu-item__details menu-item__details--price">
    <strong>
      <span class="menu-item__currency"> $ </span>
      4
    </strong>
  </p>
</li>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for element in soup.find_all(text=True):
    element.extract()

print(soup.prettify())
```

the output will be in this case:

```
<li class="menu-item">
 <p class="menu-item__heading">
 </p>
 <p>
 </p>
 <p class="menu-item__details menu-item__details--price">
  <strong>
   <span class="menu-item__currency">
   </span>
  </strong>
 </p>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Attempting to manipulate HTML using regular expressions is almost never the best idea, but this regex should do the trick for you:

```py
print(re.sub(r">[^<]+<", "><", htmlmin.minify(html)))
```